# How to extract values from a loop that stop at a specified n

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

I am trying to create tuples from 2 input. For example, my program will ask how many people is there. Let's say I write 3. The program will ask profession of each one and his salary. After that, I want the program to display a tuple containing (profession, salary) is ascending order of salary.
What im trying to achieve:

#1-Number of person = Input:(Please write the number of person you want to analyze) (Lets say 3)

#2-Profession1:Doctor
Salary1:350000
Profession2:Teacher
Salary 2:60000
Profession3:CEO
Salary3:1000000

#3-Then I want my programm to display this in the console :
('Teacher',60000)
('Doctor',350000)
('CEO',1000000)

```
number_person=input("Write the number of person: ")

for i in range(int(number_person)):
     profession=input("Write profession")
     salary=input("Write salary")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the pair in a main list, then print the list

```
values = []
number_person = int(input("Write the number of person: "))
for i in range(number_person):
    profession = input("Write profession: ")
    salary = int(input("Write salary: "))
    values.append((profession, salary))

for item in sorted(values, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the value display in ascending order of salary ? I tried Sorted() but doesn't work... Also I want the salary not displayed between '  '

Comment: @TheCodeHunter i've added the sorted part. For the quote, it's already done, you need to convert the salary to int, as I did

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just have one last question : In my code, it displays ('Teacher', '60000 ') but I want ('Teacher',60000). What am I missing?

Comment: @TheCodeHunter if you use my exact code you don’t have that issue

Answer (score 0):

make a list of strings

```
number_person=input("Write the number of person: ")
str_list =[]

for i in range(int(number_person)):
    profession=input("Write profession")
    salary=input("Write salary")
    str_list.append(f"({profession},',',{salary})")
         
for i in str_list:
    print(i)
```